Bootstrap error after upgrading
We use an upgrade shell script to manage version and we're always getting this error:
In Bootstrap.php line 57:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  Failed to locate civicrm.settings.php. By default, this tool searches the parent directories for a standard CMS (Drupal, WordPress, etal) and standard civicrm.settings.php. Symlinks and multisite configuratio  
  ns may interfere. To customize, set variable CIVICRM_SETTINGS to point to the preferred civicrm.settings.php.  

Our script installs from a zip not clones from git.
I've tried to hard set the path to the civicrm.settings.php file with different flavours of (here for WordPress in wp-config.php)
  // define CiviCRM constants here
if ( ! defined( 'CIVICRM_SETTINGS' ) ) {
      define( 'CIVICRM_SETTINGS', dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' );
  }

Same for Drupal. I could only find these 2 Bootstrap.php files but none had a line 57 that could point to this error.
./httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier/Bootstrap.php
./httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/markbaker/complex/classes/Bootstrap.php

Any idea?

Are you using cv? Bootstrap probably means this https://github.com/civicrm/cv/blob/2996f8e1429131e2052c1cd2d46a04f3e610b346/lib/src/Bootstrap.php#L174

yes we're using cv to launch DB and ext upgrades. You're right this is exactly the output.
CIVICRM_SETTINGS_PATH and CIVICRM_SETTINGS are both already declared in the wp-config.php file.
How can we address this situation?

First make sure you're using the latest version of cv. Then also note that depending on what command you're running it may not boot the cms, so it might not be loading your wp-config.php. But my guess is you're running the shell script from a folder outside the site's tree. So you can either have the script do a cd into the site's folder, and then it should find civicrm.settings.php, or you can set export CIVICRM_SETTINGS=/path/to/civicrm.settings.php in the shell script.

I think cv is up-to-date. The script itself runs from outside the site's tree but in the script we're doing a cd. We'll try to add export CIVICRM_SETTINGS=/path/to/civicrm.settings.php it seems promising
